# Differentiate code in script depending on called from another script or shell

Tags: powershell, reflection, callstack

I'm trying to differentiate code in script, A, when script, A, is called from another script,B, versus when it runs on it's own.

Script A

```
$callingScript = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source | Split-Path -Leaf
if($callingScript -eq "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"){
    # Script is run from Shell
}else{
    # Skript is called from script B.ps1
}
```

Script B

```
(...)
& "$($PSScriptRoot)\A.ps1"
```

The result is always `$callingScript` is A.ps1 and `Name` is also A.
Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a script, [`$MyInvocation.PSCommandPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.pscommandpath) contains:

- the full path of the *calling script* - if there is one.
- otherwise, the *empty string*; that is, the empty string is returned if the script was called directly f*rom the PowerShell prompt or via the CLI* - `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell) / `pwsh` (PowerShell Core).

Therefore:

```
if (-not $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath){
  # Script was called from the PowerShell prompt or via the PowerShell CLI.
  'DIRECT invocation'
}
else {
  # Script was called from the script whose path is reflected in
  # $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath
  'Invocation VIA SCRIPT'
}
```

**Note**:

- From what I can tell, `$MyInvocation.ScriptName` contains the same information as `$MyInvocation.PSCommandPath`; I've chosen the latter above for symmetry with `$PSCommandPath`
- *Functions* are ignored with respect to these properties - it is only the *enclosing script* that matters.

  - However, [`Get-PSCallStack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-pscallstack)'s output also reflects functions.
  - If you *dot-source* a script (`. ./script.ps1`) that *defines a function* that calls your target script, and you later invoke that function, `$MyInvocation.PSCommandPath` will still reflect the *script of origin* - *wherever you call the function from* (even if you call it directly from the prompt or via yet another script).

Comment: This did work. But as suggested by Patrick I ended up using an input parameter. It felt more reliable that way.

Answer (score 1):

That one should work:
Script-A.ps1

```
if ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source)
{
    Out-Host -InputObject ('Script startet with: ' + $MyInvocation.InvocationName)
}
else
{
    Out-Host -InputObject ('Script startet with: ' + $MyInvocation.ScriptName)
}
```

Script-B.ps1

```
& C:\Temp\Script-A.ps1
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> C:\Temp\Script-A.ps1
Script startet with: C:\Temp\Script-A.ps1
PS C:\> C:\Temp\Script-B.ps1
Script startet with: C:\Temp\Script-B.ps1
```

Actually I would use an input parameter (switch) to identify the case because the method above works only if you execute the file with F5 inside ISE or running directly the script inside powershell.exe.

Comment: The `$MyInvocation.InvocationName` test is so fragile that it is not worth recommending, and the caveat in your last paragraph inadequately describes its limitations: `$MyInvocation.InvocationName` is designed to reflect the name of the executing command _as specified by the caller during invocation_. 
Specifically, it is only ever the same as `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source` if the caller uses (a) the script's full, native filesystem path, (b) including the `.ps1` extension, and (c) precedes the call with neither `&` nor `.` - which cannot be reasonably assumed in general.